# changing values inside a local space by a function in that local space

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

here's a sample code:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        foobar = 'foobaz'

    foobar = 'foobar'
    print foobar
    bar()
    print foobar

foo()
```

I want to change variable `foobar` inside `foo` by function `bar`. The code above will not work, since `foobar` inside `bar` is in separate namespace with `foobar` in `foo`. A simple workaround would be making a global `foobar` and have both `foo` and `bar` can access it, but I hope there would be simpler workarounds.

Comment: And what's the use case for this? It can be done with `nonlocal` in py3, but ummm... still

Comment: @JonClements I have needed to do this before.

Comment: @JonClements An example: http://pastebin.com/2HjFSngE - To split an iterable on a given value.

Comment: @Lattyware: being distracted by football as I am, I'm probably just missing something obvious, but I don't see why that function needs `nonlocal`, or `groupby_key` at all.

Comment: @Lattyware Okay, I'm sure it has uses, but not convinced that's the best example... ie: `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(el, bool) if k]`

Comment: Well, I was clearly overthinking that one when I wrote it, an extremely good point. Ignore me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On python 3.x you can use `nonlocal` and for python 2.x try using function attributes:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        foo.foobar = 'foobaz'  #change the function attribute

    foo.foobar = 'foobar'     #declare as function attribute
    print foo.foobar
    bar()
    print foo.foobar
foo()
```

**output:**

```
foobar
foobaz
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `nonlocal` keyword, which exists in 3.x.

```
def f():
    x = None
    def g():
        nonlocal x
        x = 1
```

If you are stuck in 2.x, you can do it by having a list or similar mutable data container and accessing that as a work around.

```
def f():
    x = [None]
    def g():
        x[0] = 1
```

This works as variables do fall into scope, but won't leak out of scope. With mutable objects, we can change them inside the scope, and those changes propagate out.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in python 2.7. In python 3:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        nonlocal foobar
        foobar = 'foobaz'

    foobar = 'foobar'
    print foobar
    bar()
    print foobar

foo()
```

In 2.x, you can do:

```
def foo():
    foobar = []
    def bar():
        foobar[0] = 'foobaz'

    foobar[0] = 'foobar'
    print foobar[0]
    bar()
    print foobar[0]

foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        foobar = 'foobaz'
        return foobar

    foobar = 'foobar'
    print foobar
    foobar = bar()
    print foobar

foo()
```

Comment: You are presuming ``bar()`` will be called by that function, which could not be the case.

Comment: But its being called in the foo method as per the given sample code

Comment: That could easily be done just for the example. For an example of the counter-case, see here: http://pastebin.com/2HjFSngE.

Comment: Excuse me for my naiveness. I am just a started as a python developer. Could you be more explanatory.

Comment: Disregard me, my example is bad, as pointed out above, but there are uses.

Answer (score 0):

Even though functions are already first class objects in Python, you can create your own "functor"  or *function object* something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        self.foobar = 'foobaz'

    def __call__(self):
        self.foobar = 'foobar'
        print self.foobar
        self.bar()
        print self.foobar

foo = Foo()
foo()
```